# SQL-how to select rows which much multiple values from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

these are the tables

**Table FOURN**

```
create table FOURN(NF CHAR(2),NomF VARCHAR(10),Code int(2),VilleF VARCHAR(10));
```

**Table REVEND**

```
create table REVEND(NR CHAR(2),NomR CHAR(10),VilleR  CHAR(10) );
```

**Table VOITURE**

```
create table VOITURE(NV CHAR(2),NomV    CHAR(15),Couleur CHAR(10),Prix int(4));
```

**Table FVR**

```
create table FVR(NFCHAR(2),NV CHAR(2),NR CHAR(2),Qle  int(3)));
```

i want to retreive the number of cars(NV) which were supplied to all london vendeurs.
this is the content of the tables
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiIrp.png
this is the query i wrote

```
select distinct NV
from FVR, REVEND  
where REVEND.NR = FVR.NR AND REVEND.VilleR="LONDRES";
```

this returns V3, V5, V6 but it should return only V3 and V5
Because those are the only cars which were delivered to all London venders
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d4e4a/2

**SOLUTION**
`select NV from fvr where NR in (select NR from revend where villeR='Londres') group by NV having count(distinct NR) = (select count(NR) from revend where villeR='Londres');`

Comment: Please edit your question and add in the sample data for the two tables used in the query.  External links to pictures are not helpful; the links may even grow stale invalidating the question.

Comment: Does mysql allow double quotes?

Comment: u will get V3, V5, V6  for R5/R7,R5,R7

Comment: @GordonLinoff  yes it allows them,

Comment: @AjitKumar i shouldn't be getting V6 because V6 is not sold by all london venders (R7 and R5), it is only sold by R7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its unclear to me what the fournisseurs table should be used for here. if that table is mostly irrelevant then the following should work.

This will join the fvr table to the revendeurs table then take the distinct vehicles...unfortunately i couldn't come up with a more dynamic way... but if you have a small number of londres vendeurs it should be viable. maybe someone can improve the answer.

```
Select distinct NV FROM
  FVR LEFT OUTER JOIN REVEND ON FVR.NR = REVEND.NR
  WHERE FVR.NV IN (SELECT NV FROM FVR LEFT OUTER JOIN REVEND ON FVR.NR = REVEND.NR WHERE REVEND.NR = 'R5') 
  AND FVR.NV IN (SELECT NV FROM FVR LEFT OUTER JOIN REVEND ON FVR.NR = REVEND.NR WHERE REVEND.NR = 'R7')
```

if instead you are looking for the sum of the number of cars that were sold to both R5 and R7 without counting the ones sold to only one of the two retailers it should instead be

```
Select SUM(Qte) FROM
  FVR LEFT OUTER JOIN REVEND ON FVR.NR = REVEND.NR
  WHERE FVR.NV IN (SELECT NV FROM FVR LEFT OUTER JOIN REVEND ON FVR.NR = REVEND.NR WHERE REVEND.NR = 'R5') 
  AND FVR.NV IN (SELECT NV FROM FVR LEFT OUTER JOIN REVEND ON FVR.NR = REVEND.NR WHERE REVEND.NR = 'R7')
```

**EDIT:**

I've created an sqlfiddle to demonstrate automating this process instead of having to manually update it for every new vendor. I have placed both a stored function and a stored procedure (the function only returns the sql string)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c89e31/1

Comment: thanks a lot, R5 and R7 are the only revendeurs located in london for now, new revendeurs will be added later, which means that they should be retrieved dynamically by something like (select NR from revend where villeR='LONDRES')

Comment: Yea the problem i came across with trying to add that sort of logic was that it would bring in extra columns, mysql should be able to write a function though that automatically does my query above the way that you need it in the future. But if this answer works for you please mark it as an accepted answer

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d4e4a/2 i'm getting a correct answer but R7 and R5 should be retrieved dynamically if you can

Comment: I see what you're saying. and this problem does interest me quite a bit. I'll be leaving where i am now in a couple of minutes to drive home and beat the snowstorm. I'll try to figure a more dynamic solution out later tonight.

Comment: I had some time to go through it and i made a stored procedure that should do what you are looking for. I've edited the answer to add the sqlfiddle to the solution.

Comment: thank you, it's working, i've also found another solution  

`select NV from fvr where NR in 
(select NR from revend where villeR='Londres') group by NV
having count(distinct NR) = (select count(NR) from revend where villeR='Londres');`

Comment: awesome, that solution will run much faster than the one i posted. Glad its working for you now

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve a number, such as, the number of cars(NV) which were supplied to all london vendeurs, use the count keyword

```
select count(*) cars
from etc
```

Comment: NV represents the number of the car, it's its identifier
the result of the query here should be only V3 and V5
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d4e4a/2